# Extend an rj45 Jack

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, rj45

I want to extend the Ethernet port (of my raspberry pi) using a short bit of cable plugges in into the Ethernet Port and solider to another rj45-jack.

In the jack I have here, are some built-in coils ( looks like coils)... What are they for and will it work nevertheless?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend the Ethernet port of raspberry pi](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158025/extend-the-ethernet-port-of-raspberry-pi)

Comment: yes it is a duplicate, but there chris said, i should ask it again in this forum, because it was moved to the raspebrry pi forum and there it was declared as off-topic... Im confused...

Answer (score 2):

Use a short male-male cable and a female-female adapter. The latter are available in various styles to suit most purposes including panel mount, outlet box mount and water resistant.

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet connections are magnetically coupled rather than direct electrical connections. Historically this was done with separate components, but nowadays the magnetics get included in the jack to save PCB space.

No, it won't work, I'm afraid.